# Visual Studio 2008 Css 3 support

Tags: css, visual-studio, validation

Visual Studio 2008 supports CSS 1.0, 2.0 and 2.1 only. If I try to add sth. like text-shadow property to a class then it is outlined as invalid.

Is there a Css definition or something that I can download and make vs recognize those new properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support it because CSS 3 is not yet finalized and there are [many parts of it](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css#css3standards) that browsers do not yet support.  However, you can create your own schema as outlined in [Mikhail Arkhipov (MSFT)'s WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2007/10/19/how-to-create-custom-css-intellisense-schema-in-visual-studio-2005-and-2008.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've been googling for it, but with no effect.